# I have trouble sending text to another program, please help me

Tags: c#, firefox, explorer

I am sending some keys and text to a website in Firefox with this code:

```
 IntPtr calcWindow = FindWindow(null, "website - Mozilla Firefox");
    if (SetForegroundWindow(calcWindow))
        {
              SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
              SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); 
              SendKeys.SendWait("hello world");
        }
```

Now the problem is that it is sent too many times. For example, the text "hello word" that he sends in the text box is sent about 60, 70 times. I want each key or text to be sent only once. Thank you for your help.

I made a correction to the code but I did not get any results.

Comment: What triggers this code? Are you calling it within a loop? Or while holding down some key? The code here itself does not repeat anything, so we need more information to be able to tell.

Comment: @Xerillio yes. It used in loop.

Comment: So, I guess the answer is to remove the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After guiding the esteemed users, I realized that the problem is in the ring counter numbers, and after changing the condition and the for loop counter, I reached the appropriate result and the problem was solved.
The counter part in the for loop can increase or decrease the value of the variable. The for loop executes a block of code repeatedly.